# Indentation Error in Python 3.6.1 def

Tags: python-3.6

I had been having issues with python 3.7 for quite some time about very pointless indentations, so I decided to get back to 3.6, specifically repl.it Python 3.6.1, and as I mentioned, the errors are for no good reason whatsoever as far as I can tell, the code is as written below:

```
from random import randint

import functools
printf = functools.partial(print, end=" ")

defNuc = ['C','A','T','G']
def opNuc():

def create():
    nuc = [0]
    nucop = [0]
    length = randint(11,16)
    print (length - 1)
    for i in range(1,length):
        part = randint(1,4)
        for a in range(1,4)
        if part == a:
        nuc = defNuc[a]
        nucOp = defNuc[-a]
        if i != length - 1:
            printf(nuc[i],i,"-")
        else:
            print(nuc[i],i)
    for i in range (1,length):
        if i != length - 1:
            printf(nucOp[i],"-")
        else:
            print(nucop[i])
```

The error is at line 9, at

```
def create():
```

and as for the reason of error, it just says

```
expected an indented block
```

Edit:
This was completely my stupidity, don't take the post seriously, will be deleted in 10 minutes.

Comment: You never ended the definition of `opNuc`.

Comment: What does `opNuc` supposed to do ?

Comment: You have other indentation errors as well. A `for` loop and an `if` statement inside `create` that aren't indented.

Comment: Yes, I saw all of them, I checked this for so many times yet I have completely missed them, now I can't close the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never finished the definition of `opNuc`, so the parser is expecting an indented line to continue the body of that function. Either add a `pass` statement to provide a trivial body:

```
def opNuc():
    pass
```

or indent the definition of `create` if that is supposed to be local to the body of `opNuc` (unlikely, but possible):

```
def opNuc():

    def create():
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was my stupidity, I don't know how I missed such obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first function, `opNuc`, was never finished. I have made this simple mistake many times myself and is very easy to miss. It's easy to fix though, just type `pass` inside of the `opNuc` function and it should be fine. Hope I helped!